# How to prevent Jquery append line more than one time

Tags: jquery, find, append

my code is looking for any forms and add a new token ID line. 
I need to prevent adding the new line,  if I have this line.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "JavaScript" >
          $(document).ready(function() {
                $("form").append('<input type="hidden" name="tokenF" id="tokenID" value="#session.tokenF">');<br>
            });
    </script>
```

Please, advise me:

 Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(($('#tokenID').length) == 0) {
         $("form").append('<input type="hidden" name="tokenF" id="tokenID" value="#session.tokenF" />');

    }
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: just remove the # from #tokenID .

Comment: Thank you Lovin Nagi and appreciate your support and your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if the value is all ready there using [includes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp)

```
$("form").each(function(){
   if!($(this).html().includes("<input type="hidden" name="tokenF" id="tokenID" value="#session.tokenF">")){
       $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="tokenF" id="tokenID" value="#session.tokenF">');<br>
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for any forms that don't already have the Token ID Line.

```
$("form").find(
    'form:not(:Contains("
            <input type="hidden" name="tokenF" id="tokenID" value="#session.tokenF">'
    ).append(
        '<input type="hidden" name="tokenF" id="tokenID" value="#session.tokenF">'
    );
```

This finds form fields that do not contain the line you wish to add, then appends the line.